# Are PHP's ASP and script tags removed

Tags: php

I'm working on PHP 5.3. However while looking at [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), I find only Standard tags and short tags are documented in latest manual. Script and ASP tags are not documented. I understand they are not recommended and I do not use them. Just asking for info.

In latest manual, there is no thing about asp tags and script tags. So I believe they are removed in latest version of PHP but could not verify. I tried to look at change log but could not find if they are removed and if yes, when.

Can someone please answer if they are still supported (even though depreciated) in latest version of PHP? If no, in which version they were depreciated and when they were completely removed?

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags

Comment: it is still allowed check this page also [Escaping from HTML](http://in2.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

Comment: @bansi Yes it seems they are still available. Just wondering why they are not included in Manual with deprecated note.

Comment: They are not yet depreciated Quote from manual `There are four different pairs of opening and closing tags which can be used in PHP. Two of those, <?php ?> and <script language="php"> </script>, are always available. The other two are short tags and ASP style tags, and can be turned on and off from the php.ini configuration file. As such, while some people find short tags and ASP style tags convenient, they are less portable, and generally not recommended.`

Comment: @bansi Please go through the manual link in the question. I guess they are latest manual or may be I should start looking us1.php.net instead of www.php.net/manual
Just confused with two versions of manual.

Comment: The link in the question is not mentioning much about tags. i am referring to the page [Escaping from HTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) which is next on the left menu

Comment: it is one of my pet peeves when people say 'depreciated' when they mean 'deprecated'. >:(

Comment: @sevenseacat - Probably browser spelling engine.

Comment: @sevenseacat Correct, I mean deprecated. However I guess both spellings are correct. US/UK English difference and in my case, Indian English too. Just for example, both 'color' and 'colour' are correct. Lets not go to that discussion but around the world, English has many versions with slight difference.

Comment: both spellings are not correct - the two words mean totally different things.

Comment: @sevenseacat agreed after reading [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45295/why-is-there-confusion-between-depreciated-and-deprecated). Deprecated is correct. I want to add more but this is not correct forum for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMG , I did not even knew before that ASP tags can be used..

Anyhow, I do not know which version of the manual you are looking at , but Look here :

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags

For shorthand tags it say :

> Note: This directive also affected the shorthand <?= before PHP 5.4.0,
> which is identical to `<? echo`. Use of this shortcut required
> short_open_tag to be on. **`Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.`**

for Script and ASP : (Example two is script)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

> While the tags seen in examples one and **two** are both always
> available, example one is the most commonly used, and recommended, of
> the two.

> Short tags (example three) are only available when they are enabled
> via the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP
> was configured with the --enable-short-tags option.
>
> **ASP style tags** (example four) are only available when they are enabled
> via the asp_tags php.ini configuration file directive.

So in essence if the Document is correct, and updated -  , they are not yet deprecated.

Further info here : [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

[DUPLICATE ?]

Comment: The note you linked isn't for asp type tags, that's for shorthand tags ^^

Comment: @Jon part of the question .. or actually of the answer

Comment: @ObmerkKronen This is not exact answer and I already went through links you shared, still thanks for answer. I believe they are still supported but not given in latest manual as they are deprecated. (Manual link is in question) Just looking if someone can confirm this.

Comment: @KapilSharma why should this be deprecated? It is also mentioned in the documentation, but many people do not use them and you need where to look for them in the documentation.

Comment: @KapilSharma check the next link [Escaping from HTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) on the left menu in the page you have mentioned in the question

Comment: @KapilSharma - the exact same thing is in the links you shared . see the little menu on the left . Unless we are being redirected to different pages based on geographic location..

Comment: @ObmerkKronen no difference in any English pages served as far as i checked. I checked it from Asia, Europe, US and Middle-east

Comment: @bansi - I know. Just that OP is insisting the manuals are not the same ?